# Remove permissions on a folder in Office 365 with PowerShell

Tags: document-library, powershell, permissions, office-365

I am trying to remove permissions from a folder and then add new ones.

My script adds the permissions successfully but when I try and get rid of the permissions it inherited it's just not working, it just adds the new permissions on to it.

I am adding to a document library in Office 365

```
Write-Host "inheritance reset"
$item.ResetRoleInheritance()
$item.BreakRoleInheritance($true,$false)
$Context.Load($item)
$context.ExecuteQuery()
Write-host "Inheritance Broken"

$global:test =$true

if($isgroup -eq $true){
      $groups = $web.SiteGroups

      $context.Load($groups)

      $context.ExecuteQuery()

      $group = $groups | where {$_.Title -eq $groupAD}

}else{
      domainUser = $groups -replace '\\', '/'
      $fullUserName = ([adsi]"WinNT://$domainUser,user").fullname
      $groups = [string]$fullUserName
      if($groups -eq ''){
           $groups = "Rob Ireland"
      }
      $group = $Context.Web.EnsureUser($groups)
}

$collRdb = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection($context)                                
$collRdb.Add($roleDef)                                                             
$collRoleAssign = $item.RoleAssignments                               
$rollAssign = $collRoleAssign.Add($group, $collRdb)
$context.ExecuteQuery()
Write-host "$Permission have been added at $folderName for $groups"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$item.BreakRoleInheritance($false,$false)
```

You will have to specify the first parameter as **False**, which means all the permissions from the parent will not be copied over.
See the documentation for [BreakRoleInheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/LIbrary/ee547386.aspx) .