# Create Subfolder WIthout Inheriting Permissions in PowerShell

Tags: permissions, inheritance, unique, subfolders

I need to create a subfolder (in a SharePoint document library) without inheriting permissions from the parent folder. I then need to assign specific permissions to the newly created subfolder. What is the best way to go about doing this? Thank you.

I used PowerShell to create Folder A inside a SharePoint 2013 document library.
I used PowerShell to create a subfolder of FolderA. This subfolder is named FolderB. I do not want FolderB to inherit any of FolderA's permissions. However, when I create FolderB, FolderB inherits all of FolderA's permissions. Is there a way to tell SharePoint not to apply FolderA's permission to FolderB when FolderB is created? Here is my code:

```
$FolderA = $list.AddItem("", [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileSystemObjectType]::Folder, "Folder A");
$FolderA.Update();
$FolderA.BreakRoleInheritance("true");
$FolderA.Update();
Write-Output "Folder created " $FolderA.Url


$FolderBURL=$list.ParentWebUrl +"/" + $FolderA.Url;
write-host $FolderBURL;
$FolderB = $list.AddItem($FolderBURL, [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileSystemObjectType]::Folder, "Folder B");
$FolderB.Update();
$FolderB.BreakRoleInheritance("true"); 
$FolderB.Update();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `BreakRoleInheritance` with `$true` or `$false` you do the following :

- you are assigning the folder with unique permissions.
- Any new permissions added to the item are only applied to the item.

Only the difference :

- `$true` to copy role assignments from the parent object to this object;
- `$false` to assign only the current user to security roles.

So For `Folder A` you can set `BreakRoleInheritance` to `$true` or remove the following two lines

```
 $FolderA.BreakRoleInheritance($true);
    $FolderA.Update();
```

For `Folder B` you should can set `BreakRoleInheritance` to `$false`

The final code should be

```
$FolderA = $list.AddItem("", [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileSystemObjectType]::Folder, "Folder A");
$FolderA.Update();
$FolderA.BreakRoleInheritance($true);
$FolderA.Update();
Write-Output "Folder created " $FolderA.Url


$FolderBURL=$list.ParentWebUrl +"/" + $FolderA.Url;
write-host $FolderBURL;
$FolderB = $list.AddItem($FolderBURL, [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileSystemObjectType]::Folder, "Folder B");
$FolderB.Update();
$FolderB.BreakRoleInheritance($false); 
$FolderB.Update();
```

Check also [Syntax of BreakRoleInheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee550474.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/149089/57662

It will stop the inheritance but you will have to apply whatever permissions you want.

Comment: Please point out what part is differing in the answer from that link and the users code above

Comment: $item.BreakRoleInheritance($false,$false)

Comment: so in this format;-

$FolderB.BreakRoleInheritance($false,$false)

Comment: Your two last comments doesn't help much. They are different from each other, and don't have the same result. Instead - update your answer by hitting the edit button and explain what you really mean. Thank you!

Comment: Benny what are you reading? my last 2 comments? I was asked to point out what differs, So I did. The answers do indeed differ. If I wrote more it would only detract from the answer.

So agian the user has this;- $FolderB.BreakRoleInheritance($false);

Comment: I suggested using this;-
$FolderB.BreakRoleInheritance($false,$false)

How can people not see the difference between these two lines of Code
$FolderB.BreakRoleInheritance($false)
$FolderB.BreakRoleInheritance($false,$false)

Comment: @user3271150 Instead of posting solutions in comments, would you be so kind to add them to your answer instead?

Comment: What you are still missing is the fact the answer is in the link

Comment: Benny Skogberg, really, what is your problem? The answer is in the link. The comments above are merely pointing out what is already in the link within the answer. To change the answer would detract from answer... and make it more confusing.